# Retrieve all IDs for duplicate vertices in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

## Problem

I am running a query which finds duplicate vertices by the `name` property. I would like to know the IDs for *all* the corresponding vertices.

At this time, only the ids in the where clause are returned.

### Example graph

Here is a toy example graph. There are two vertices with the same name `ex`.

```
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('X').property('name', 'ex')
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.addV('Y').property('name', 'why')
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.addV('Y').property('name', 'ex')
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.V().elementMap()
==>[id:0,label:X,name:ex]
==>[id:2,label:Y,name:why]
==>[id:4,label:Y,name:ex]
```

### Detecting duplicates

When I find the duplicates and get the `elementMap()`, the IDs are only for the vertex matched in the `where` clause.

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('X').as('x').V().hasLabel('Y').as('y').where('x', P.eq('y')).by('name').elementMap()
==>[id:4,label:Y,name:ex]
```

Whereas I would like to see the `id` for both which would be `id:0` and `id:4`

I would like something like:

```
==>[[id:0,label:X,name:ex], [id:4,label:Y,name:ex]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You had actually got very close

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('X').as('x').
......1>   V().hasLabel('Y').as('y').
......2>   where(eq('x')).by('name').
......3>   select('x','y').
......4>     by(valueMap().by(unfold()).
                with(WithOptions.tokens)).
......5>   select(values)

==>[[id:0,label:X,name:ex],[id:4,label:Y,name:ex]]
```